# using windows form serialization class getting errors

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, visual-studio-2013

I'm using a custom cs file from here (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86503/Saving-the-state-serializing-a-Windows-Form?msg=4819352#xx4819352xx) to serialize my windows form into an XML file.

I'm afraid I might not be using the correct events in order to trigger the serialization because only some of the form data is being serialized.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FormSerialisor.Deserialise(this, Application.StartupPath + @"\serialise.xml");
        }

        catch (InvalidCastException theError)
        {

        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        FormSerialisor.Serialise(this, Application.StartupPath + @"\serialise.xml");
    }
```

Here's a screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xRKH.jpg

I've used coding practices to prevent duplicate object names by leaving the default names intact and just changing the "text" field or adding labels. My only guess is that the program is quitting before it finishes serializing the data.

Is this the correct handler to be calling this from?

Comment: hard to answer without knowing the serialization process.  Also the screen shot is a screen shot (game I think), not sure what to take from it.

Comment: what errors? Please update your question post.

Comment: the class I'm using provided by another is supposed to basically save the form data to an xml file. but when I re-launch it, it only loads part of the data. I was wondering if I used the correct event handler (Form1_FormClosing) or if I should have used another...

Comment: remove that from the equation, just serialize the form via a button click and see if it works.  obviously disable your `form closing` event for that test.

Comment: actually I just went ahead and used an ArrayList and streamwriter/streamreader to do the same thing. it mostly works now.

Comment: but that's a separate issue I'll post shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaking you have NumericUpDown control which is not handled by the FormSerialisor. You need to make sure that all the controls that you are using are handled in the FormSerialisor.

I hope this helps.